# My glitch server's container stats don't show CPU as red, but my Arras server is less smooth than most servers

Tags: arras

My server was made from CX's template at `arras-template.glitch.me`. Inside Glitch's "Container Stats," CPU isn't red or yellow, but my Arras server feels less smooth than what I might get on a normal server. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem specific to CX's Glitch template.

To resolve this issue, go to `config.json`.

```
- "runSpeed": 0.7,
+ "runSpeed": 1.0,
```

This will help increase a statistic known as Update Rate.

This will not reduce CPU usage.